# MongoDB get first and last document in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

How can I get first and last document based on `time` field.
I can use `$group` and get `$first` and `$last` document, but I don't need grouping here, just get first and last full document. Maybe I could use `slice`? This query doesn't work:

```
{
  "aggregate": "353469045637980_data",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$match": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "time": {
              "$gte": 1461369600
            }
          },
          {
            "time": {
              "$lt": 1461456000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "first": {
          "$slice": 1
        },
        "last": {
          "$slice": -1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: First and last value of what? Can you be more specific, perhaps include a bunch of test documents and your expected output?

Comment: I'm expecting list with two entries [first, last]. Where first and last are full documents from collection

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well you need `$group` but you can simply use a constant (e.g. `null`, see [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)) for its `id` so that it results in a single group. [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) then refers to the document itself which you can use with `$first` and `$last` like so

```
$group: {
  _id: null,
  first: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
  last: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
}
```

Of course you can introduce further `$project` stages to shape that data into an array (as you mentioned you want a list) etc.

As a side note you may want to introduce a `$sort` stage to make sure `$first` and `$last` have a proper meaning.

Comment: Did you write the query ? I still don't understand. Can you please share the final query to get the first and last document based on creation date

Comment: Is there any way to get last two documents on the group by stage?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage, combined with `$sort`/`$limit` stages:

```
// { time: ISODate("2021-12-04"), b: "hello" }
// { time: ISODate("2021-12-07"), b: "world" }
// { time: ISODate("2021-12-05"), b: "oups"  }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $facet: {
    first: [{ $sort: { time: 1 } }, { $limit: 1 }],
    last:  [{ $sort: { time: -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }]
  }},
  { $set: { first: { $first: "$first" }, last: { $last: "$last" } } }
])
// { first: { time: ISODate("2021-12-04"), b: "hello" }, last: { time: ISODate("2021-12-07"), b: "world" } }
```

The `$facet` stage allows us to run multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its result is stored as an array of documents.

Each field is thus produced by its own aggregation pipeline whose first stage `$sort`s documents by the `time` field (in opposite orders), followed by a `$limit` stage that'll only keep the first item (the smallest as defined by the chosen ordering).

The second part of the pipeline (the `$set` stage) is just there to clean-up the `$facet` output format.

---

Note that a `$sort` followed by a `$limit` stage is optimised by Mongo (see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-sort----limit-coalescence)). This allows the sort operation to only maintain the top n results (in our case only 1 element) as it progresses.

Also note that our `$sort` stages will benefit from having an index on `time`.

Comment: Does $sort here really use index? I have a collection with 11 million doc, time is indexed. It takes 0.001 sec if I do `db.collection.find({}).sort({time: 1}).limit(1)`, but it takes >73 seconds if I do aggregate as you suggested. Any explanation?

Comment: @newman Damn, you're right: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#index-use . That's quite sad, there's no real reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, $facet really makes sense for this, and it's very semantic at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer the question directly but would have helped me a lot when I came across this question.

You could (like DAXaholic explained) use the following query to get the corresponding documents:

```
[
  $sort: {...},
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    first: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
    last: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
  }
]
```

The problem I faced was that I got the following error: `Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.`

To work around this issue (without using disk for sorting) you could use:

```
[
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    first: { $min: "$time" },
    last: { $max: "$time" }
  }
]
```

The advantage is that you don't need to sort and therefore might not run in the 100 MB memory limit. The downside is that it does not return the entire document (where `$min` / `$max` matches) but only the value of the property (in this example `time`).